# Pandas dataframe | dictionary inside column | round and sort within column | Best way to do it?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
languages = ['en','cs','es']
counties = ['us','ch','sp']
count = [32, 432,43]
a = {('p', 0.25937605905953339), ('q', 0.2001602214732502)}
b = {('r', 0.5937605905953339), ('4', 0.12001602214732502)}
c = {('l', 0.35337605905953339), ('r', 0.42001602214732502)}
score =[a, b, c]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'language': languages,'county': counties, 'count' : count, 'score': score})

  language  county  count   score
0   en       us     32      {(p, 0.25937605905953337), (q, 0.2001602214732...
1   cs       ch     432     {(r, 0.5937605905953339), (4, 0.12001602214732...
2   es       sp     43      {(r, 0.42001602214732503), (l, 0.3533760590595...
```

Now I want to the score value will be round off by 4th value and sorting based on score

```
  language  county  count   score
0   en       us     32      {(q, 0.2001), (p, 0.2593)}
1   cs       ch     432     {(4, 0.1200), (r, 0.5937)}
2   es       sp     43      {(l, 0.3533), (r, 0.4200)}
```

I am able to do this for one entry

```
a = {('p', 0.25937605905953339), ('q', 0.2001602214732502)}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a)
df1.columns = ['Name', 'Score']   
df1.Score = df1.Score.apply(lambda x: round(x,4))
df1.sort_values(by=['Score'], inplace = True)
```

I can do it for for complete data frame using for loop, but I want to do it in better way like list comprehension, lambda, map, filter etc. Can someone please help

Comment: On which value of the score do you want do sort your data?

Comment: The numeric value inside score i.e. the dictionary within row sorted

Comment: But you have 2 numeric values, which one has priority over the other one?

Comment: If you take '4' as numeric then its string name here. please take this type of numeric value : 0.25937605905953337, within score

Comment: Avoid nesting data structures inside data frames. Keep columns with primitive values only: `str`, `bool`, `int`, `float`...

Comment: yes, but this the data i received from client and now I need to provide the result in same way only. This is not right data structure but :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom function which would round the second element and sort based on the second element in the tuple and return a set:

```
f = lambda x: set(sorted(zip([i[0] for i in x],
       [round(i[1] ,4) for i in x]),key=lambda x:x[1]))
df1['score'] = df1['score'].apply(f)
print(df1)
```

---

```
  language county  count                       score
0       en     us     32  {(q, 0.2002), (p, 0.2594)}
1       cs     ch    432    {(4, 0.12), (r, 0.5938)}
2       es     sp     43    {(l, 0.3534), (r, 0.42)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use pandas apply method with dict of comprehension:

`df1['score'] = df1.apply(lambda row: {(elt[0], round(elt[1], 4)) for elt in row['score']}, axis=1)`

Comment: thanks, its rounding off but not sorted the value I want like it do {(p, 0.2594), (q, 0.2002)} but I want {(q, 0.2002), (p, 0.2594) }